# Sharepoint 2013 _layouts redireciton

Tags: 2013, layouts

I'm in the process of migrating to SP 2013. In my current production site I've incoming requests 'posting data' to a layouts page ex: _layouts/mycustompage.aspx. I see that in SP 2013 the _layouts directory is moved to _layouts/15 causing all incoming post requests not to work.

Is there a solution to support post-requests during redirect? or at least support both the urls at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

can you deploy your solution to both the 14 and 15 hive?  Check out this link:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607534.aspx and the compatibilitylevel parameter.

```
Install-SPSolution $SolutionName -GACDeployment -Force -Confirm:$false -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}
```